# What are these white things on new leaves?

Tags: diagnosis, diseases, leaves

I have roselle planted. But I see these on the leaves. What are these?

[image][image]

Edit: Added closeups

Comment: Could you manage to post a bigger close up picture?

Comment: Do they happen to look like butterfly or moth eggs? There are a wide variety of appearances for them. They're not always clustered, either. Those white butterflies we have just deposit a single egg at a time and fly off. Those eggs look a lot like this: https://entomologytoday.org/imported-cabbageworm-egg/

Comment: How do you remove these then? By brushing them off? I have added closeups

Comment: These look like round grains of salt.

Comment: They definitely look like eggs, but not cabbage worm eggs.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like butterfly (or moth) eggs